# Como alterar tipo e collation da coluna por migration laravel

Tags: laravel, migrations

Tenho duas colunas que precisam ser alteradas. `qntd_vagas` esta como `varchar`, tenho que alterar para `integer` e a outra coluna é `confidencial` que esta como `text`, tenho que alterar para `tinyint`. Fiz a migration no laravel e quando executo da erro de syntax. O que esta errado, como posso arrumar esse erro e fazer a migration rodar sem da esse problema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Uma alternativa seria usar algo como DB::statement('alter table vagas modify qntd_vagas int unsigned not null default 0');

Comment: Caso não seja ambiente de produção a resposta do Lucas seria a melhor opção. Cuidado php artisan migrate:refresh vai limpar totalmente sua base

Answer (score 0):

Os seguintes tipos de coluna podem ser modificados: `bigInteger`, `binary`, `boolean`, `date`, `dateTime`, `dateTimeTz`, `decimal`, `integer`, `json`, `longText`, `mediumText`, `smallInteger`, `string`, `text`, `time`, `unsignedBigInteger`, `unsignedInteger`, `unsignedSmallInteger`, `uuid` e `timestamp`.

Use este comando no seu terminal `php artisan migrate:refresh`, ele vai recriar o seu banco de dados.

Eu recomendo dar uma olhada na documentação:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#roll-back-migrate-using-a-single-command

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Sobre o comando `php artisan migrate:refresh` , eu ate posso rodar isso, mas seria em localhost, não iria resolver muita coisa, porque depois eu rodaria isso no servidor de produção, e isso eu não posso, poderia afetar outras tabelas ja criadas e com dados, o único meio que me foi permitido é criar uma migration para fazer o update dessas colunas.

E sobre a documentação, eu dei uma olhada também, mas a versão que esta sendo utilizada atualmente em produção, infelizmente, é a versão 5.4 do laravel. 

Mas obrigado mesmo assim.